# Python scraping email address from href link

Tags: python, email, href, screen-scraping

I want to get all email adresses from these schools (green links):
http://www.schulliste.eu/schule/

right now I have the code for getting all href links but how can I click on every link and scrap the email address from every clicked link?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re
import requests

def getLinks(url):
    html_page = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href',))

    return links

print(getLinks("http://www.schulliste.eu/schule/"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the links to each school, and then run a request on each:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_emails(_links:list, _r = [0, 10]):
  for i in range(*_r):
     new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})
     if new_d:
       yield new_d[-1]['title']

d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/schule/').text, 'html.parser')
results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
print(list(get_emails(results)))
```

Output:

```
['schuleamhasenwald-gue@freenet.de', 'kita-stmartin@htp-tel.de', 'wundertuete@stephansstift.de', 'a.haeupl@igs-baltic-schule.de', 'kindergarten@bothel.de']
```

Comment: Don't you think it will be more sound to do a regex pattern for an email and search for that all through the page?

Comment: I don't think all email addresses are required - just the one for that particular school as per its summary data in the "Allgemeine Informationen:" box

Comment: Yes I will have all email adresses

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks it works nice, to get ALL email I adresses I have to change "[0, 10]" or? Is it also possible with python to send the same email to all schools?

Comment: @clauhau To grab all the emails, you can just iterate over `_links`. The range was for demonstration purposes, as looping over all on my machine would take too long. Please bear in mind, however, that due to the number of schools listed, sending an automated message to each may very well constitute spamming.

Comment: ok so I can just delete "(*_r)" from "for i in range"? Im quite new to python ...

Comment: yes maybe you are right with spamming...  than I have to find I way that the emails dont end up in spam

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another function similar to `getLinks` e.g. called `getEmail`, where you pass it the URL of a subpage, it uses `urlopen` and BeautifulSoup (just as you have done in the first function) to get the HTML content and extract the email address from that page.

Your main code then needs to call `getEmail` for EACH link retrieved from `getLinks`.